# Please identify component marked 33L 1C

Tags: identification

I have an electronic card for DC charger. Please help to identify the component marked 33L 1C in the photo.

[image: component]

Comment: Hi, As you have now asked about the IC markings in you [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612228/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-uc2824a-ics), I am removing all mentions of that from *this* question to prevent duplication of effort in both places, and because it was difficult to read here. || Does the answer regarding your diode identification solve *this* question? If so, please consider "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" it to effectively close the question. Thanks.

Comment: The IC marked with the LT logo and the coil to the left suggests this diode is part of a switched DC/DC converter circuit. If that diode is blown, then you should replace the LT regulator IC as well. Whenever the regulator blows, this diode tends to blow too, and vice versa. If you only replace one of them, it might blow up yet again.

Answer (score 3):

The diode appears to be an SSA33L.  Datasheet is here:

[Vishay SSA33L Data Sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88883/ssa33l.pdf)

The marking is designated as "33L":

[image: 33L Diode]