# What is the difference between these two UC2824A ICs?

Tags: markings

I need make replacement any problem will happen to circuit.

Both ICs are UC2824A but the difference is the last two lines on the IC.

[image]  [image]

Comment: mahmoud hussein - Hi, I have removed all mentions of your questions about this IC from your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612211) since you now asked about it here. In future: (a) Identification questions should be limited to one device; (b) Please be careful not to duplicate questions, as it can waste the effort of different site members, who might reply to both questions, without seeing the other one. For more details of site rules and etiquette here, please see the [tour], the [help] and the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see anything in the Texas Instruments datasheet about those being feature codes.  Usually, one of those two lines is a code for the manufacturing date.  The other could be a code for the plant location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , It means no any problems comes if I remove one and install other

Comment: The device marking has a footnote: _"There may be additional marking, which relates to the logo, the lot trace code information, or the environmental category on the device."_. It isn't further specified, but shouldn't be of any importance.